# Import sequences in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, import, package

I want to organize a package with this structure:

```
/program.py
/__init__.py
/data/
/data/__init__.py
/data/method_1.py
/data/method_2.py
/data/classes.py
```

program imports method_1 and method_2, method_1 and method_2 import classes. But I get an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'method_1'. How should I organize this package and what should I write in **init**.py files?

```
program.py:

import __init__
from data import classes
from data import method_1
from data import method_2
...


__init__.py:

__all__ = ['data']
from data import *


/data/__init__.py:

__all__ = ['classes', 'method_1', 'method_2']
from method_1 import *
from method_2 import *
from classes import *


/data/method_1.py: (and also /data/method_2.py)

import classes
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method_1`, `method_2`, and `classes` [are all in the `data` package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), hence:

```
# data/__init__.py
from .method_1 import *
from .method_2 import *
from .classes import *
```

...

```
# data/method_1.py
from . import classes
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `data` package is in the same directory with `program` this should work:

```
#program.py
from .data import classes
from .data import method_1
from .data import method_2

# data/__init__.py
from .method_1 import *
from .method_2 import *
from .classes import *


#data/method_1.py
from . import classes

#data/method_2.py
from . import classes
```